# d3.nest to aggregate and count json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load json data into d3 and aggregate it using **d3.Nest**

```
<script>
        d3.json("/table", function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var Ben = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.district; })
        .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
        .entries(data.List);

        console.log(Ben);

    });

</script>
```

Not able to follow why I'm receiving the following Error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefine*

Comment: It looks like that `data.List` is `undefined`. What do your `console.log` print?

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov console.log returns my json data from the "/table" url.
But length is being used on an undefined variable. Is it some problem related with the scope of the variable?

Comment: `leaves` is not a variable, it is just the parameter you use to name the array inside the `values` property, it can be any other name, parameter's name doesn't matter. That being said, please share the exact structure of `data.List` (just the first couple of objects, not the whole array).

Comment: I understand. But using leaves, wouldn't cause a problem I suppose?

Comment: data in the "/table" page is JSON with the following structure:
{"name": John, "age":22, "qualification": Masters, "Location": India}
Now, there are many countries that could be present. I basically want to aggregate by country and get a count to be used in d3

Comment: The problem is clear now: there is no `district` in your data.

Comment: I had skipped the district field in the example I gave. Even if I had tried "Location" instead, it wasn't working out.

Comment: Instead, if I used an "error" argument in the outermost function along with the data argument it works fine. I guess its a case of the page loading fully before the data is loaded? With the callback and error argument it seems to be working fine.